# Reinstalling windows 10 w/o losing apps

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, reinstall

My windows 10 machine is having issues with the optical drive and HDMI port and I think my best course of action is to re-install windows 10. THIS question is about that process.

This machine has windows 10 installed as an upgrade from windows 7, so during that process all my existing apps survived. I would like to be able to "reinstall" windows 10 w/o deleting all my other apps, just 'refresh" the OS in a manner largely (I assume) analogous to how the original Win7->Win10 upgrade went. Is this possible? And if so, pointers?

I still have the option to roll back to Windows 7, so plan B might be to do that and then re-apply the Win10 upgrade. However, I might have installed a few apps since the original upgrade so I'd like to know if "plan-B" would also delete those apps (restoring me to the apps I had when I last ran Win7).

(Note, I stupidly neglected to active the restore point system after installing Win10, so rolling back is unfortunately not an option for me.)

Thanks

Mike

Comment: You should be able to just launch the Windows 10 installer and choose to keep everything.  Of course a simpler solution is solve the actual problem before you do that.

Comment: I think that any sort of rollback would restore a previous version of the registry, which could cause a problem for these applications.

Comment: You say: **`My windows 10 machine is having issues with the optical drive and HDMI port`** have you looked for updated drivers of applicable devices, etc? What issues are you experiencing? Perhaps this will help someone give you additional advice or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The optical drive and the HDMI port are in no way related, so you're dealing with two separate issues here. For the HDMI port try installing the latest version of the driver for your video card. For the optical drive maybe try plugging it into a different port. The optical drive definitely should not have any problems just because of a Windows upgrade. I don't think there's a way to reinstall the entire Windows 10 without losing your apps. There is a way to fix system files, you can try that. Here's an article describing it:
http://www.howtogeek.com/222532/how-to-repair-corrupted-windows-system-files-with-the-sfc-and-dism-commands/